# what does (filter (\y -> not(x == y)) xs) mean?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to work out how to remove duplicates from a list in haskell. I found the answer below to my problem...

```
type Regist = [String]
type ListRe = [Regist]

rmDup :: ListRe -> ListRe
rmDup [] = []
rmDup (x:xs) = x : rmDup (filter (\y -> not(x == y)) xs)
```

on stackoverflow but I don't understand what particular parts of the last line mean or do espically

```
(\y -> not(x == y))
```

I've never seen \y used before or "not" which is puzzling me quite a bit!

I would of added a comment to the answer but i don't have enough reputation on my account to add a comment on the answer (was someone elses question), to ask about the answer as well as the fact it was from 2010 and I can't seem to get in contact with the person who answered!

Any help is appreciated!

thank you :)

Comment: `not True = False` and `not False = True`. The `\x ->` syntax is for lambdas (anonymous functions).

Comment: equivalent to `/=`  https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Eq.html

Comment: Oh yeah just realised the lambdas (anonymous functions), I've learnt about them but never used them before myself, thank you :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\name -> expr` syntax defines a lambda function, also known as anonymous functions.  This is just an alternative way to define a function in Haskell that is particularly useful when you don't want to have to give a name to it.  For example, in

```
> map (\x -> x + 1) [1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
```

It would be quite a pain to have to write it as

```
> let add1 x = x + 1 in map add1 [1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
```

since this name is only used once, and this general pattern is very, very common in Haskell (and other functional languages)<sup>[1]</sup>.  You can even use this syntax when defining normal functions:

```
> let add1 = \x -> x + 1 in map add1 [1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
```

And the compiler essentially does this to all your functions anyway, since this form is easier to manipulate internally.

The `not` function you see being used is a built-in that simply performs a logical NOT on a boolean value:

```
not :: Bool -> Bool
not True = False
not False = True
```

So the expression `\y -> not (x == y)` is equivalent to `\y -> x /= y`<sup>[2]</sup>.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> For this example you can actually leave out the lambda if you really wanted and write this as `map (+1) [1, 2, 3]`, since Haskell lets you partially apply operators, a very handy feature I constantly wish I had in other programming languages.  Operator sections as they're known are quite useful and can help reduce a lot of unnecessary typing.

<sup>[2]</sup> Or at least should be, although you could define a type where the instance for `Eq` defines both `==` and `/=` to always return `True`, but expect this to act strangely with code that expects them to behave well.

Comment: I understand lambda part, but I don't understand how can y be compared too, does y in (x == y)  represent the \y lambda or x, or the next element in the list?

Comment: @JakeEmbx The `x` comes as the first element of the list provided to `rmDup`, and `y` is introduced in the lambda passed to `filter`, so `y` is representing an element of `xs`.  `y` is only in scope for the lambda passed to `filter`, but using operator sections this could instead be written as `rmDup (x:xs) = x : rmDup (filter (/= x) xs)`.  It takes the first element of the list, `x`, keeps it, then filters out all elements equal to it in the remainder of the list.  This is then fed back into `rmDup` and the process continues for the next element of the list, which must be distinct from `x`.